# Issue with AccumulatorOperators Max when creating aggregation pipeline

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I'm trying to convert following Mongo shell aggregation query into Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('Orders').aggregate([
{ $group: {
    "_id": {"book":"$bookingId"},
    "docs": {$push: '$$ROOT'}
  }
},
{$project: {
   latestOrd: {
      $filter: {
         input: "$docs",
         as: "item",
         cond: { $eq: ["$$item.bookingVersion", { $max: "$docs.bookingVersion" }] }
      }
   }
 }
},
{ $unwind: "$latestOrd" },
{ $replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$latestOrd"}}
])
```

Query fetches all orders with highest booking version (for example one bookingId may have many documents with version 3).

This query works fine in Mongo shell but I have issue with Spring Data version of it:

```
Aggregation.group("bookingId").push(Aggregation.ROOT).as("docs");
Aggregation.project().and(filter("docs")
          .as("item")
          .by(valueOf("item.bookingVersion")
                .equalToValue(AccumulatorOperators.Max.maxOf("docs.bookingVersion"))))
          .as("latestOrd");
Aggregation.unwind("latestOrd");
Aggregation.replaceRoot("latestOrd");
```

Spring generates Mongo query similar to one that I've provided above except $max accumulator:

```
{ "$max" : "$$docs.bookingVersion" }
```

for some reason it adds double dollar sign instead of single dollar sign and as a result I have following error:

```
'Use of undefined variable: docs' on server 127.0.0.1:27017
```

I'm using spring-boot-starter 2.1.0.RELEASE and 4.2 version of Mongo server.
I appreciate any help on this.

Input documents:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5f847811ebcd1a51a0196736",
    "status": "REJECTED",
    "bookingId": "1",
    "bookingVersion": 4,
    "operation": "CREATE"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5f847811ebcd1a51a0196735",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "bookingId": "1",
    "bookingVersion": 4,
    "docNumber": "7",
    "operation": "CREATE"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5f847811ebcd1a51a0196734",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "bookingId": "1",
    "bookingVersion": 3,
    "docNumber": "6",
    "operation": "CREATE"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5f847811ebcd1a51a0196738",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "bookingId": "2",
    "bookingVersion": 1,
    "docNumber": "8",
    "operation": "CREATE"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5f847811ebcd1a51a0196737",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "bookingId": "2",
    "bookingVersion": 2,
    "docNumber": "9",
    "operation": "CREATE"
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5f847811ebcd1a51a0196736",
    "status": "REJECTED",
    "bookingId": "1",
    "bookingVersion": 4,
    "operation": "CREATE"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5f847811ebcd1a51a0196735",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "bookingId": "1",
    "bookingVersion": 4,
    "docNumber": "7",
    "operation": "CREATE"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5f847811ebcd1a51a0196737",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "bookingId": "2",
    "bookingVersion": 2,
    "docNumber": "9",
    "operation": "CREATE"
  }
]
```

Comment: I checked this with Spring boot starter 2.3.2.RELEASE and mongo version 4.0.10. It produces correct query and gives expected output. Upgrading spring boot version might fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you @Harshit, but upgrading spring boot version is not an option for me. I will try to use AggregationExpression instead of AccumulatorOperators.Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue might be with 2.1.0.RELEASE version of spring boot but upgrading it is not an option for me.
To make this work I've created AggregationExpression instead of `AccumulatorOperators.Max.maxOf("docs.bookingVersion")` part.

Here is a method for it:

```
  private AggregationExpression buildMaxExpression() {
    return new AggregationExpression() {
      @Override
      public Document toDocument(final AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new Document("$max", "$docs.bookingVersion");
      }
    };
  }
```